# jQuery Validate and linking form errors to their respective fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate and I have a form split into sections. On submission it validates and I am returning the error box method that contains all of the errors. I would like to be able to specify them as links so clicking an error would take the user to that field. Possible out of the box?

js:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname:   {required: true},
        lastname:    {required: true},
        email:       {required: true},
    },
    messages: {
        firstname:   {required: "Step 2: Your first name is required."},
        lastname:    {required: "Step 2: Your last name is required."},
        email:       {required: "Step 2: Your email is required."},
    },
    errorContainer: "#error_container",
    errorLabelContainer: "#error_container ul",
    wrapper: "li",
    submitHandler: function() {
            ajax('{{=URL('new_post')}}',
    }
});
```

And the HTML it generates looks like:

```
<div id="error_container">
    <ul><li><label for="firstname" generated="true" class="error_two" style="display: inline;">Step 2: Your first name is required.</label></li></ul></div>
```

I would like this to link back to the firstname field if at all possible. Thanks.

EDIT: I see I didn't explain myself well enough. The HTML I *want* it to generate would be like:

```
<div id=error_container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="link_to_field">Your first name is required.</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where it creates clickable anchors back to the respective fields. Any way to do this? I've seen the "focus on error" method listed below and that certainly is a good way to do it the meantime but I would like to be able to have the user click any of the errors and go to those fields in any order they choose. It works in a multi-step format that's why I would like this, otherwise, it would all be right there and they can just click each field normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the quick way is to use the validate option focusInvalid, It will focus the last active or first invalid element on submit

  ```
  $('#form').validate({
     .
     focusInvalid: true,
     .
  });
  ```
- the long way, which should achieve what you want to do, is to make use of the showError callback in validate option

  ```
  $('#form').validate({
     .
     showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
         // errorMap - the map of errors
         // errorList - array of errors
         // construct the list of error items with links that focus on the invalid elements

         // default behavior
         this.defaultShowErrors();
     },
     .
  }
  ```

Comment: Edit: Just realized what your second method is doing. Let me try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. It's strange that it still generates the labels but clicking them does return you to the respective field. Add in some hover styles and it looks the exact same as an anchor. Giving you 50 points for that one.

Comment: well if you comment out `this.defaultShowErrors();`, the default labels won't be displayed.  Didn't know about this feature of the error label actually bringing you back to its respective field.  My suggestion was trying to use the `errorMap` or `errorList` to construct an html unordered list with links that would focus to a particular field.

Comment: Actually copying your code EXACTLY as above does not focus at all. I think that's what you're saying your intention was. Instead, it works exactly how I wanted, which is to connect the label with the input. Just just like normally clicking a label provides focus on the corresponding input, this is doing the same thing. So once I realized how it was actually linking back to the field, I realized I DO want to keep the labels. Thanks again a million.